# Trie in Nodejs with million records

Tags: node.js, express, trie

I implemented a trie tree with nodejs its working fine, but the issue is I have around 1 million records to process which took some time to prepare the Tree. Now I am confused when to prepare the trie, on server init and is it okay place this tree in memory. 
Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: This trie tree of yours, need to be created once and then used throughout the app life cycle? Or it may need to be updated too?

Comment: No its juts a one time process for a day, I am just concerned about the memory usage of app, how efficiently I can handle this at server start